# If once a reference is initialized to an object, it cannot be changed, why does this work?

Tags: c++, reference

I've read that once a reference is initialized to an object, it cannot be changed.
The following code works, so perhaps I am misunderstanding the concept? (Or do they mean this more in an immutable sense?)

```
int main()
{

    int x = 4;
    int& j = x;
    cout << j << endl;
    int y = 5;
    j = y;
    cout << j << endl;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do what you think it does. Print `x` out too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The following code works, so perhaps I am misunderstanding the concept?

Indeed I'm afraid you are misunderstanding the concept. The expression:

```
j = y;
```

Does **not** re-bind `j` so that it becomes a reference to `y`: rather, it assigns the value of `y` to the object referenced by `j`. Try this after the assignment:

```
cout << (&j == &x)
```

And you will see that `1` is printed (meaning `j` is still an alias for `x`).

After initialization, a reference becomes an alias for the object it is bound to. **Everything you do on the reference, you do it on the object being referenced**.

A reference cannot be re-bound or unbound, and it practically becomes just an alternative name for the object it is bound to.

Answer (score 3):

You're just assigning to the reference, not binding it to a new "object" (technically, not an object). If you print out `x`, you'll see that it too has changed (omg) :)

Answer (score 3):

What was being conveyed is that a reference cannot be *rebound*. The assignment is affecting `x`, not `j`. The variable `j` on the other hand is still bound to `x` even after the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The reference can't be made to point to a different object at a different Address, but as here, the value of the object itself can be changed.